# How do I get a list of the classes compiled into my Flex app?

Tags: apache-flex, dependencies, flash-builder

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Determining linkage dependencies in Flex applications](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3049714/determining-linkage-dependencies-in-flex-applications)

I have several Flex applications in a project, and I would like to know if there's a way to get a list of the classes (and ideally, other assets) that are being compiled into each one. I want an easy way of making sure I've kept things separate and there aren't unnecessary dependencies. Any ideas? I'm running Flash Builder 4.

Comment: Check the answer to this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3049714/

Answer (score 0):

What about a `grep` through the imports?

```
$ grep -R 'import ' src/ | awk '{ print $2 }' | sort -u
flash.events.ContextMenuEvent;
flash.events.Event;
...
$
```

Answer (score 0):

Change the swf file extension to zip, incompressible and look at the manifest?