# Determining linkage dependencies in Flex applications

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, flash-builder

I have a large Flex project with two Applications in it. A lot of code is shared between these Applications. However, the smaller of the Applications does not require much of the code that the larger one does. I'm trying to ensure that code that isn't required by the smaller application isn't getting compiled into it.

Is there an easy way for me to determine which files within my project are being compiled into a particular Application?

Comment: "I'm trying to ensure that code that isn't required by the smaller application isn't getting compiled into it". This is what the compiler does by default. If your app doesn't depend on a class, it won't be included in the swf (unless you explicitly force the inclusion).

Comment: @Juan Yes, but I was asking how to find out what classes an application depends on. In a small project this is obvious, but with hundreds of classes, it's easy to make mistakes.

Comment: I agree. But since you mentioned that you wanted to ensure that not required code wouldn't be compiled into the swf, I thought I'd point out this isn't the case by default.

Answer (score 2):

Ah, I managed to discover the solution to this shortly after posting.

The Flex compiler supports a -link-report flag that produces an XML file which describes all of the linkage dependencies for the applications in your project.

Flex 2 Documentation:
http://www.adobe.com/livedocs/flex/201/html/wwhelp/wwhimpl/common/html/wwhelp.htm?context=LiveDocs_Book_Parts&file=performance_118_19.html

Flex 3 Documentation:
http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/help.html?content=modular_4.html

Comment: Check this out too: http://www.kahunaburger.com/2008/03/08/air-link-report-visualizer/